# How to optimize a O(kn) query that looking for matching alerts between 1 000 000 (k) alerts and 5000 (n) smartphones (~24 hours time process)

Tags: python, mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I have **smartphones (5000 added per day)** in a MySQL database

Smartphone (Id: int PK, Price: double, DisplaySize: double, Ram: int)

and **1 000 000 alerts** created by user to be notified if a smartphone matching with their preferences is added;

Alert (Id: int PK, PriceMin: double, PriceMax: double, DisplaySizeMin: double, DisplaySizeMax: double, RamMin: int, RamMax: int)

I have a batch (executed everyday) that will check the added smartphones (~5000) and finds the corresponding alerts like this :

```
for smartphone in smartphones:
    smartphone_alerts = session.query(Alert).filter(
    smartphone.price >= Alert.price_min,
    smartphone.price <= Alert.price_max,
    smartphone.displaySize >= Alert.displaySize_min,
    smartphone.displaySize <= Alert.displaySize_max,
    smartphone.ram>= Alert.ram_min,
    smartphone.ram<= Alert.ram_max,
    ).all()

    #add alerts to a dict
```

It takes over than **24h** to get all the matching alerts for 5000 smartphones and 1 000 000 alerts !

Is there a way to optimize this ? A better database model ? Efficient algorithm ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question after you [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info): we need more information to help you. And, please tell us whether you use [tag:sql-server], [tag:mysql], or some other database by adding the appropriate tag.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks, I edited it. I am using MySQL. I didn't give so much information because I think this is not a question of only optimizing this SQL query but more on how I should model an architecture that allow me to do this spec in a convenient time...

Comment: I recommend shrinking the datatypes -- For example: a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` for price instead of an 8-byte `DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given much information. In particular you didn't tell us anything about your `Alert` query.

I guess you are doing some sort of `SELECT * FROM Smartphones;` query, reading every row into RAM, then reading the Alerts the same, and then filtering the rows pair by pair. [O(n**2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions): Number of Smartphones x number of Alerts = 5,000,000,000. No wonder it takes all day!

If you used a query like this you'd get MySQL to do that work. That's what it's made for.

```
SELECT Smartphone.Id, Alert.Id,
       Smartphone.Price, Smartphone.DisplaySize, Smartphone.Ram
  FROM Smartphones
  JOIN Alerts   ON Smartphones.Price >= Alerts.Price_min
               AND Smartphones.Price <= Alerts.Price_max
               AND Smartphones.DisplaySize >= Alerts.DisplaySize_min
               AND Smartphones.DisplaySize <= Alerts.DisplaySize_max
               AND Smartphones.Ram >= Alerts.Ram_min
               AND Smartphones.Ram <= Alerts.Ram_max
```

I suspect, but I'm not sure, these indexes will help a lot

```
CREATE INDEX pricerange ON Alerts(Price_min, Price_max DESC)
CREATE INDEX price ON Smartphones(Price)
```

I put the indexes on Price because they're more likely to be [selective](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_index_selectivity.html) than indexes on display size or RAM.

Comment: @TrivialWorker - But what it fast "enough"?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, in minuts insteads of hours

Comment: @TrivialWorker - (Good.  The only speed-ups I could think up were messy and non-trivial.)

Comment: Running that `.query(Alert)` five thousand times, and loading a megarow each time, cannot have been cheap.